# Hilbert's inequality for $ \left|\sum _{{r\neq s}}{\dfrac {u_{{r}}\overline {v_{{s}}}}{r-s}}\right|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality, reference-request, complex-numbers

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_inequality), Hilbert's inequality states that
$$ \left|\sum _{{r\neq s}}{\dfrac  {u_{{r}}\overline {u_{{s}}}}{r-s}}\right|\leq \pi \displaystyle \sum _{{r}}|u_{{r}}|^{2}\, ,$$
for any sequence $u_1$, $u_2$, $\dots$ of complex numbers.

I wonder whether the inequality is still valid for bilateral series and for
$\sum _{{r\neq s}}{\dfrac  {u_{{r}}\overline {v_{{s}}}}{r-s}}$, with $v_s\neq u_r$. I think yes for both questions. For example, I think that
$$ \left|\sum _{{r\neq s}}{\dfrac  {u_{{r}}\overline {v_{{s}}}}{r-s}}\right|\leq \pi \displaystyle \sqrt{\sum _{{r}}|u_{{r}}|^{2} \sum _{{r}}|v_{{r}}|^{2}} \, ,$$
but I can't some references for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are right. A quick reference is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwcGlSbzgzZVdYZkk/view , page 82.